# Upload media on server with WorkManager and Notification Service

Tags: android, android-workmanager, foreground-service

I want to upload media files having a large size (it may be in GBs also). I am using an android `WorkManger` from the Jetpack component for providing background upload functionality.

How to show notification regarding uploading media as Google Photos does? Is there any way to implement it using the work manager itself?

Answer (score 2):

WorkManager v2.3 added few methods to publish progress from a Worker to allow an app to updates its UI.

You can see how to use this functionality in the documentation for the latest WorkManager v2.3 alpha: [Observing intermediate Worker progress](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/intermediate-progress).

Keep in mind that, [since alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.3.0-alpha02), the progress information is only available while the worker is in the **RUNNING** state. When the worker reach a final state, the progress information is going to be deleted from the WorkManager database. If you need to persist some information to handle interruption of your worker (because the upload took more than 10 minutes or because a constraint on the availability of an unmetered network is not satisfied anymore) you need to save this information in your own data store. WorkManager progress API is not intended to be used for this and **cannot be used for this** because the progress is deleted once your worker is stopped.